# C++20 Returning Non-type Variadic Template Tuple

Tags: c++, c++20, variadic-templates, stdtuple

Currently using g++11.3.0, C++20.

I'm trying to compile the code below, where the function `foo` takes an arbitrary number of template arguments and returns a tuple that contains a value for each template argument. The code compiles and runs for me when I use the statements `foo<int>()` and `foo<float>()`, but runs into an error when I use the statement `foo<int, float>()`:

```
error: no viable conversion from returned value of type 'tuple<typename __unwrap_ref_decay<float>::type, (no argument)>' to function return type 'tuple<int, float>'
```

However, if I change the return type from `std::tuple<Args...>` to `auto`, it compiles and runs for all three statements. Is return type deduction the only way to go or is there a way to avoid using the `auto` keyword?

```
template <typename ...Args>
std::tuple<Args...> foo()
{
    return std::make_tuple(([] ()
    {
        // Do some stuff....
        // Return value....

        return Args();
    }(), ...));
}
```

Comment: You are using the *comma operator*, so the function always returns a tuple of one element. it should be `return std::make_tuple([] () { return Args(); }()...);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use the syntax for folding expression using **comma operator**, instead you need:

```
template <typename ...Args>
std::tuple<Args...> foo()
{
    return std::make_tuple([] ()
    {
        // Do some stuff....
        // Return value....

        return Args();
    }()...);
}
```

Comment: Does the current function return a tuple of references already? Or just a tuple of l-values? If I wanted to return a tuple of l-value references, what would I have to change? I tried changing the return type to `std::tuple<Args&...>` and using `std::tie`, but it gave me the error `no matching function for call to 'tie'`.

Comment: As written, `foo<int, float>` returns `std::tuple<int, float>` (you would need `foo<int&, float&>`, but). [`std::make_tuple`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/make_tuple) is the wrong tool (unless you use `std::reference_wrapper<X>`), the lambda should also return a reference (and reference are not default constructible)... Several changes, hard to write expected code with those broad information.