# C++20 Returning Non-type Variadic Template Tuple of References

Tags: c++, c++20, variadic-templates, stdtuple

Currently using g++11.3.0, C++20.

This is a follow up from a previous [query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75352560/c20-returning-non-type-variadic-template-tuple).

I have a function `foo` that takes an arbitrary number of template arguments and returns a tuple that contains a value for each template argument. However, the function currently returns a tuple of l-values. I would like to return a tuple of l-value references. I've tried changing the return type to `std::tuple<Args&...>` and using `std::tie()` instead of `std::make_tuple()`, but gives me the error:

```
error: no matching function for call to 'tie'
```

The lambda in the function actually returns a non-local variable with the respective data type, so the line `return Args();` is just there as a substitution to provide compilable code for this post.

```
template <typename ...Args>
std::tuple<Args...> foo()
{
    return std::make_tuple([] ()
    {
        // Do some stuff....
        // Return non-local l-value....

        return Args();
    }()...);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A lambda without specified return value always returns by-value, not by-reference. Specifically it returns with a return type of `auto` by default. So your call to the lambda never produces a lvalue, always a prvalue. `std::tie` then fails, because it accepts only lvalues.

If you want to have the lambda return a lvalue reference, you need to specify its return type. I wouldn't make it specifically a lvalue reference though. You can have it deduce the appropriate value category automatically with `decltype(auto)`:

```
[] () -> decltype(auto)
{
    // Do some stuff....
    // Return non-local l-value....

    return Args();
}()
```

(However, `Args()` is a prvalue, not a lvalue, so this will still deduce to a non-reference type. If you actually want to have the lambda return a lvalue reference, then actually give the `return` statement a lvalue as operand.)

Alternatively you can specify `Args&` as the return type of the lambda explicitly.

After that, you can use `std::tie` or alternatively `std::forward_as_tuple`. The latter will correctly deduce whether the references should be lvalue references or rvalue references automatically, while `std::tie` assumes lvalue references and will fail otherwise. Typically it is desirable that the value category is deduced, although in your situation it might be a potential source of error since it would have caused UB instead of a compilation error with your wrong return type on the lambda.

Then you can also use `auto` as return type for `foo`, so that the automatically deduced value category applies, but that is a matter of style.

---

On a side note, if your lambdas have side effects, note that the order in which the lambdas will be evaluated is indeterminate. You can not rely on any particular ordering.